# How to combine array list string in java?

Tags: java

I have some arraylist string with keyword inside like that !

A windows is arraylist string with keyword is bold 
 Struct of window : 9 words before + keyword + 9 words after

You can see some  window overlaping 
[image]

How to i combine that arraylist  to receive like that :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question and accept answers to some of your previous questions if you would like answers to this question.

Comment: Thanks ! I have done, sorry i do't know about it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not too worried about performance, a simple `subList/equals` matching is very easy to write:

```
    String[] texts = {
        "sunset lake michigan michigan alaska water florida "
        + "peninsula third largest water seventh largest water "
        + "percentage edit list largest country",

        "michigan alaska water florida peninsula third largest water "
        + "seventh largest water percentage edit list largest country "
        + "subdivision list political",

        "third largest water seventh largest water percentage edit list "
        + "largest country subdivision list political geographic "
        + "subdivisions total edit references"
    };
    List<String> joined = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String text : texts) {
        List<String> textAsList = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
        final int N = joined.size();
        final int M = textAsList.size();
        for (int k = Math.min(N, M); k >= 0; k--) {
            if (joined.subList(N - k, N).equals(textAsList.subList(0, k))) {
                joined.addAll(textAsList.subList(k, M));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(joined);
```

This prints:

```
[sunset, lake, michigan, michigan, alaska, water, florida,
peninsula, third, largest, water, seventh, largest, water,
percentage, edit, list, largest, country, subdivision, list,
political, geographic, subdivisions, total, edit, references]
```

The algorithm works as it says: to build `List<String> joined`, given a `List<String> textAsList`, we find the longest `subList` matching between the "tail" of `joined` and the "head" of `textAsList`.

Comment: I have document with some keyword : My goal is find some textchunks have keyword inside :
To do this a have some step :

Fist : i find a window is arraylist string content : 9 words befor keyword + keyword + 9 words after keyword. for  Each keyword.

 after this step : we have some window (arraylist string ) of keyword , window may be overlaping 


Second i must combine overlaping windown 

after this step will have textchunks that content keyword .

Problem here is if windown do't ovelaping , it still  add to ListString joined .
I have some keyword after jon i must recive

Thanks in advandce

Comment: @tiendv: I have no idea what you're trying to say. Edit the question with more information for the benefit of everyone trying to help. Give examples to illustrate the different cases. The more the better. Also give bounds on operating parameters, because the best algorithm for this would be quite complicated, but an easy but practical solution seems to exist.

Answer (score 0):

See [*How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) and these [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextPane.htm) using [`DefaultHighlighter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultHighlighter.html).

Addendum: Ah, I thought you just needed the view. For the model, consider the [*Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt), discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285434).

Comment: I don't mention about how to show it and combine it in screen. I mean i have some arrayList string like win1,win2, win3 .
How can i combine win if it have overlaping !
Thanks

Comment: @tiendv: Amended, but it looks like @polygenelubricants may have a good idea; this problem reminds me of matching overlapping gene sequences.

Comment: @thrasgod: yes, it does remind me of that too, and I was about to suggest that the most state-of-the-art algorithm probably involves suffix tree/suffix arrays.